# How to programatically write a PST file

Tags: c++, .net, outlook, pst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create an Outlook PST file using .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724789/how-can-i-create-an-outlook-pst-file-using-net)

How can I write an Outlook PST file with headers? Preferably in .NET, though C++ or anything else would be useful too

I have looked at the PST SDK by Microsoft, but it appears to be read only.
 The only code I have found is the CodeProject article "Writing Email to the File of the PST Format", but this code can't write e-mail headers - just body and subject.

Comment: @R0MANARMY it's a useful link but I don't think it's a duplicate. That answer requires Outlook to be installed on the machine where the code runs.

Comment: @chris Please check whether the question linked above is a duplicate. If it is, this question should be closed/deleted. If not, please edit the question to (a) include a link to the other question, and (b) explain how your question is different from that. E.g. if you are looking for a solution that does not require Outlook to be installed, that information should be added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use Microsoft's Messaging API (MAPI).  There's plenty of help available online, and there's a sample app called MFC Mapi that one of the Microsoft guys wrote to demonstrate how the API works.

Answer (score 0):

Would the .pst file format documentation be of use to you? From the brief look I took, it seems to document the format itself, so you can implement reading/writing functionality. I don't know how detailed it is, since I haven't used it myself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210%28v=office.12%29.aspx